# How to implement Elements on every Page app/views/elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, element

I have recently seen in a project that uses rails under app/views/elements the file _navbar.html.erb which contains html code for a navbar. And it appears on every page without having to call it on the pages where it appears.

This is the code in the file:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <%= link_to "Pandora", defined?(root_path) ? root_path : "#", class: "navbar-brand" %>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if defined?(Devise) %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

My question is where is it set up so that it displays the navbar on every page. I would also like to know if I were to style it, would I just have to link a css file in the _navbar.html.erb?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is setup in the layout in the `app/views/layouts directory`. By default, you are using `application.html.erb`.

Including this snippet in your layout file `<%= render 'layouts/header' %>` will render partial view with the name header.html.erb on each site. If implementing navbar located at the top of the page, you probably want to put it somewhere above the `yield` line (which renders the current view template).

**Styling:**

Nope, in Rails, you will just have to put it either in the `application.css / application.scss` or include your file with css styles in one of these application files. If you are new to the Rails ecosystem, then go ahead and read about [asset pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html).

Comment: So if I wanted to added a style sheet to the navbar I would like the file in the header of application.html.erb correct? What would be the path for the location of the .css file?

Comment: Yes, this would work, although thanks to rails asset pipeline, you wont receive any benefit of not compiling it into one large common css. But it would work ok though :)

Comment: I have a file named application.css.scss that was generated in assets/stylesheets would I write in css or scss in there? I should be able to just write the styling for the navbar in there and then the navbar should be style correct?

Comment: Yes, you can do directly in that file - but it is not recommended, rather create a separate stylesheet file for the navbar and then include it in the application.css.scss